# Dynamic menu: ID item with subitems

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I have a dashboard that is supposed to help the user keep track of a list of chores. The chores are listed as `menuSubItem`s in the `sidebarMenu`. So, if the file corresponding to a chore has been created, I want a check-icon to be placed beside the `menuSubItem`.

I'm having a hard time understanding why do the `menuSubItem`s wait untill I have clicked on `test` and then `home` again to be rendered... I tried printing out `input$test_subitems` and it seems that I can't track when `test` is selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",

  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarMenu",
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Item with subitems", tabName = "test",
               uiOutput("test_subitems"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody( id = "dashboardBody" )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe(cat('1:', input$sidebarMenu, '\n'))

  output$test_subitems <- renderUI({
    print(input$sidebarMenu)
    tabs <- c("st1","st2")
    lapply(tabs, function(tab) {
      menuSubItem(icon = NULL, paste('Test:', tab), tabName = tab)
    })
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought I didn't find a way to id an item with subitems, it seems that `suspendWhenHidden` does the trick for me:

```
outputOptions(output, "test_subitems", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```